# How to get the device architecture inside a kernel?

Tags: aleagpu

Just as the title asks. Both

```
let blockReducer = BlockReduce.RakingCommutativeOnly<float32>(dims,DeviceArch.Create("sm35"))
```

and

```
let blockReducer = BlockReduce.RakingCommutativeOnly<float32>(dims,worker.Device.Arch)
```

fail on compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `let blockReducer = BlockReduce.RakingCommutativeOnly<float32>(dims,worker.Device.Arch)` should be called outside the kernel. Then there are no problems at all.